# How to check, if the edited result exits in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, edit

I have edit an item. and my code is :

```
let articleName = $('[placeholder="Article name"]');
articleName.click().clear().sendKeys('Test Item Edited');
saveItem.click();
```

however when i try to check the test case by:

```
expect(articleName.getText()).toContain('Test Item Edited');
or
expect(articleName.getAttribute("Test Item Edited")).toEqual('Test Item Edited');
```

it shows error "Expected '' to contain 'Test Item Edited'."

in my source code after edit the item the article name is not found. is that the reason?

```
<input _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" matinput="" required="" maxlength="80" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,80}" id="mat-input-611" placeholder="Article name" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
```

I am new to protractor. so I am not sure how to handle this.

Comment: If the text is not present in DOM, then I don't think you can apply assertion on it.

Comment: yeah the text is not present in DOM. that's why I am clueless how to overcome the problem. anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: have you tried `expect(articleName.getAttribute("value")).toEqual('Test Item Edited');`

Comment: @RamPasala it worked finally. thanks a lot!!

Comment: ok so it worked with `getAttribute('value')` right? I will add it as answer so you could accept it because it would help others having the same question!

Comment: @RamPasala. yes it worked with getAttribute('value'). please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `getAttribute()` tag, when you are entering text in a textbox field , you could access the entered text with `value` attribute.

So your `expect` assertion would be as follows-

```
expect(articleName.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('Test Item Edited');
```